# Where and when did the traditional “wave across the ditch” take place?

Tags: nasa, space-shuttle, kennedy-space-center, astronauts

I’ve heard that before a launch American astronauts had one last chance to see their family by waving across a ditch (which apparently wasn’t really a ditch?). I’m curious, where and exactly when (day before, day of launch) did this take place?

Answer (score 4):

For the Space Shuttle, it took place at the launchpad, one day before the launch.

Mark Kelly described it in his [book about his wife](https://books.google.com/books?id=jRtjZpFeqPAC&pg=PT250&lpg=PT250&dq=astronaut%20wave%20across%20the%20ditch%20launch%20pad&source=bl&ots=uejbTSNp5B&sig=T1LnkOMLI0p5PcICK8Z-PFhSF8U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiAptDg06zdAhVmmK0KHdBtDikQ6AEwCXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> When Dan was finished, buses were waiting to take our family members
>   several miles away to the launchpad, where my crew and | would show up
>   to meet them. It’s another NASA tradition—the extended family
>   farewell.
>
> Everyone stood behind a rope line, facing the launchpad. On my earlier
>   flights, we stood with a ditch separating the crew from the guests, so
>   the ritual came to be called “the wave across the ditch.” This time,
>   the six of us drove up in our convertibles, got out, and stood
>   together on the other side of the rope. Because we were still in
>   quarantine, we couldn’t get too close to anyone. I always feel like a
>   circus animal as everyone takes photos at the wave across the ditch.
>
> Because the crew's wives had been given physicals and deemed healthy,
>   they were allowed to join us for photos. Gabby had been in these
>   photos during my past missions, but since she was still not up to
>   being seen publicly, she wasn’t there for this one. So it was just me,
>   my five crew members, and their five wives. We were all lined up and
>   everyone was clicking away.I| smiled through it, but I was thinking of
>   how the sixth wife belonged in those photos.
>
> Twice in the history of the shuttle program—the final launches of
>   Challenger and Columbia—the wave across the ditch was the last time
>   astronauts’ loved ones saw them alive. Everyone on both sides of the
>   rope—astronauts, wives, siblings, cousins, parents—was aware of that.

(a page or so earlier, he states it's the day before the launch)